# Mismatch between php version and php-config version

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Recently, I updated from php5.5 to php5.6 following this link:https://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/ (i.e. adding the ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 repository)

After that php-config --version is showing 5.5.9 while php -v is showing 5.6.18.

I had to install some extensions using pecl. But pecl follows php-config and installs extensions not compatible with php5.6. None of my newly installed versions are working due to this. I am stuck on this for 2 days. Any help is appreciated.

PS: Somewhere I found that I may have two different php-config binaries located in different paths, but I could find only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

php-config is part of the `php5-dev` package.

In case the ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 repository provides that as well (it should)

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

should fix that.
(I wonder though why there's a isn't a dependecy declared that updates the `php5-dev` package when `php5` is updated....)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev
```